# Blacklist IP addresses based on number of 404s in Apache

Tags: hardening, ids, apache

I'm getting a lot of hackers spamming my domain with requests for files that just don't exist. This is eating up a lot of my allotted bandwidth and I'd like to blacklist these IP addresses.

Is there is a way to automatically blacklist IP addresses in Apache once they have requested X number of files that 404 in a specified time frame?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) does exactly what you ask.

It monitors your log files looking for certain patterns and then executes whatever action you specify. You can block an IP for a length of time.

It does require some skill in regex, but it comes packaged with regex testers.